# postgres docker not connected with pgadmin4 in Linux

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I've PostgreSQL 9.6 docker container. Running on port 32768. I try to connect the server to pgadmin4 its shown following error.

In pgAdmin4:
[image]

Docker container:
[image]

In /etc/postgresql/9.6/main/postgresql.conf i added the following line

> `listen_addresses='*'`

In /etc/postgresql/9.6/main/pg_hba.conf:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to look up the ip adress of the docker container? docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' container_name_or_id

Comment: Ya @Jakob I tried with DB container IP also it's not connecting. While doing `telnet localhost 32768` its showing `Connected to localhost` if I use container IP shown as `telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused` i tried this outside docker.

Comment: Are you able to connect using psql?

Comment: I have the same problem and I'm able to connect with psql. My web application running in localhost also connects to the database.

Comment: @RômuloCollopy Try to connect with "psql" command if working then add system local IP like 172.17.0.1 instead of localhost.

Comment: Thanks @Gokulp, but I've already done that and it didn't work... But I've got a satisfactory set up using docker-compose